# What does 'financial drain' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Soviet involvement in the war was deeply unpopular in the USSR, being fought largely by conscripts among whom there were many casualties, but it ended not so much because of popular discontent but because the military and ***financial drain*** on the USSR was too great to be continued.

What does '**financial drain**' mean?

Comment: And what is "military drain"?

Comment: See [***drain***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/drain) "13. that which gradually exhausts strength, resources, etc."

Answer (score 2):

A [drain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain_(plumbing)) is something where water can flow away, never to be recovered again.

[image]

<sub>(picture taken from Wikipedia)</sub>

In this context, it is used as a (quite common) metaphor: the USSR simply had to put too much money into the war, which they would never see again.

Comment: On a more personal level, sometimes people will use _financial drain_ to refer to an item that is costly to maintain (such as a boat, an extra house, or even an overpriced insurance policy, e.g.).